# 'Jacobian' of QR decomposition of a rectangular matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, statistics, volume, gaussian-integral, stiefel-manifolds

I want to calculate the volume of real Stiefel manifold $V_{k}(\mathbb{R}^N)$ .
$$
 V_{k} (\mathbb{R}^N) = \{ H \in M(N, k, \mathbb{R})| H^{T}H = I_{k} \}
$$
((^T) denotes transposed matrix. $M(N, k, \mathbb{R})$ : real $ N \times k$ matrix. $I_k$ : identity matrix of dimension $k$.) My understanding is that this volume can be calculated using Gaussian integral like in the following question.
[Show that $\int_{\mathbb R^n}e^{|x|^{-n}}dx=$ Volume of n-sphere](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/831039/show-that-int-mathbb-rnex-ndx-volume-of-n-sphere)

In this paper(https://lib.dr.iastate.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?referer=https://www.google.com/&httpsredir=1&article=2492&context=rtd), the volume of Stiefel manifold is calculated like following.

Let $Z$ be a real $ N \times k $ with rank $ N $. By the fact of QR decomposition, it can be (uniquely) decomposed to a product of $ H_{1} \in V_{k}(\mathbb{R}^N) $ and upper-triangular matrix $T$ with positive diagonal elements $(Z=H_{1}T)$. Let $H_{2}$ be an $ N \times (N-k) $ matrix such that $ H= [H_1 : H_2] \in O(N) $. We write $ H = [h_1, \ldots, h_k : h_{k+1}, \ldots , h_{N}] $ where $ h_1, \ldots, h_k, h_{k+1}, \ldots, h_{N} $ are column vectors of $H_{1}, H_{2}$ with $N$ components.

The Gaussian integral used to caluculate the volume of Stiefel manifold $ V_{k}(\mathbb{R}^N) $ is as follows
$$
 \int_{\mathbb{R}^{kN}} \exp \left[ - \frac{1}{2} tr( Z^T Z ) \right] (dZ) = (2\pi)^{-kN/2}
$$
where $tr$ is trace of matrix. The paper says on page 14, 'Then the differential $dZ$ is defined as'
$$
 (dZ) = \prod_{i=1}^{k} t_{ii}^{N-i} \bigwedge_{i \leq j}^{k}dt_{ij} \left( \bigwedge_{i=1}^{k} \bigwedge_{\alpha=i+1}^{N} h_{\alpha}^{T} dh_{i} \right).
$$
But unfortunately I cannot derive this formula from the above discussion.
So, my question is 'How to derive this formula?'.

I think this is derived by calculating the 'Jacobian' of the transformation $ Z = H_1 T $. But I don't know how to calculate the Jacobian of this matrix tranformation.
I would be grateful if someone could explain how to derive this formula. Thank you in advance.
I'm a physics student and beginner in Statistics, Measure theory and manifold.